# State between impossible and possible

Tags: word-request

I was wondering if there is a word for mediatory state between impossible and possible? That means when we think something is impossible and there are ways to make it possible. So can we have a word to define the state of covering the distance between that impossible to possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking about "possibilization". Not a word in typical dictionaries, but definitely was used before.

Comment: That reminds of the legen - wait for it - dary Barney Stinson's video resume. [Possimpible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ao036CaZLng)

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Good one. We should have the word "possibilization" :D

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can think of *the closest* - **feasible**.

This **may not sound** the exact word but if you think about the noun *feasibility*, this term sounds the closest. The term *doable* or *viable* also shows the probability of something between 100 percent possible or 100 percent impossible.

Note that we use these terms **only** when we are not 100 percent sure about its possibleness or impossibleness.

I've often heard my clients asking to check the feasibility of their projects i.e. they first ask me whether it's possible or not. Then only they give me a green signal.

> [feasible](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/FEASIBLE) - Capable of being done with means at hand and circumstances as they are

[+1 as I never thought of this before!]

Comment: Yes. Feasible you can say. But it puts a limit with the condition that some sets of solutions can be done, rest all cannot be. I guess yes, we don't have a word until now that can show the hope of going forward to possibles without the condition.. :(

Btw.. +1 for suggesting the word! :)